# Django - button url

Tags: python, django, url, frontend

I get a weird question. I am creating a function to add friend to list, here is my view and url.

```
@login_required(login_url='user:login')
def friend_add(request, friend):

    friendship = FriendShip(
        from_friend=request.user,
        to_friend=friend
    )

    friendship.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

url(r'^add_friend/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

While I call the url in the template:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Friend" onclick="location.href='{% url 'user:add_friend' friend=post.poster %}';">
```

An exception will happens while *loading* the webpage:

> Reverse for 'add_friend' with keyword arguments '{'friend': }' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/add_friend/$']

After several attemptions, the webpage can be loaded with the input been removed

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Friend" onclick="location.href='{% url 'user:add_friend'%}';">
```

(This is weird enough because the view is asking for input)

However, when I click on the button, another exception happens:

> friend_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'friend'

I get really confused about this question. Really appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**: `path(..)` is available from Django-**2.0**.

The problem here is that `friend` is *not* in the URL:

```
url(r'^add_friend/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),  # no parameter
```

You can for instance use the primary key (`pk`) for the friend by specifying a [**`path(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path):

```
path(r'add_friend/<int:friend>/', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

In case you work with [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), you can use [**`url(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url) with a regex:

```
url(r'^add_friend/(?P<friend>[0-9]+)/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

And now we can use the primary key of the friend in the reverse url:

```
<input
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-info"
    value="Add Friend"
    onclick="location.href='{% url 'user:add_friend' friend=post.poster.pk %}';"
>
```

(multi-line to make it easier to read).

Comment: Note: `path` is available only in django 2.0. For django version < 2.0 use `url` instead.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Really appreciate that! I was about to ask about the 'path'

Comment: Right, I am missing that in the url. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM: thanks. Updated with a remark and alternative for django-1.x :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Shouldn't it be re_path instead with old capture syntax if you are using regex,  and just text if you are using path capture syntax

Comment: @iklinac: afaik, `re_path` was introduced in Django-2.0. The `url(..)` variant is specified in case somebody that uses django-1.x visits this question. But I guess using `path` is more elegant, since here we specify *what* the type of the parameter is, not how that parameter looks like.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem according to Django documentation path doesn't use regex as input but string, that is what I was trying to point out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path
The route argument should be a string or gettext_lazy()

Comment: @iklinac: but `r'...'` is *not* a regex, it is a *raw string*. Here `r'abc' == 'abc'` it is only when we use for instance backslashes that there is a problem (i.e. `r'a\n' != 'a\n'`). The type of a `r'..'` is still a string. For instance `type(r'abc') == str`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you had starting and ending regex character until last  edit -> ^add_friend/<int:friend>/$, so  everything is fine now

Answer (score 2):

Your urlpattern shoul also have friend argument like this:

```
url(r'^add_friend/(?P<friend>[0-9]+)/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

This will allow you to pass integer ids of friend object to the url like this `add_friend/12`.

Comment: Oh right, that part is missing, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**data-ajax-target** call particular URL of Django in HTML button

```
<button type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light text-dark"  data-ajax-target="{% url 'collections' %}?collection={{ collection.collectionID }}" }">
<span>{{ collection.choice_label }}</span>
</button>
```